# Autodesk data center for forge other than US and Europe?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I know there are two data centers, US and Europe, but are there more data centers available for other regions?

Comment: This site is for specific questions related to programming. We are not Autodesk customer service. Contact them directly for questions related to their services. For more information about this site, see the [help].

Answer (score 0):

Autodesk is planning to add more data centers over the next couple of years, but at this point we only have US and EMEA.